# VSCode Remote-SSH runs code in external terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote, remote-development

I am using Remote-SSH for VSCode to connect to a linux server from a Windows machine.

When executing python code in VSCode, both inputs and outputs are sent into my own external terminal, instead of opening a new internal terminal in VSCode.

Basically, the external terminal is shared with VSCode. This creates problem with tmux too, as everytime I run some code a new session is created.

[image]

I have also set `launch.json` configurations like this: `"console": "integratedTerminal"`, but nothing has changed.

When using VSCode on my local machine I do not experience this issue.

How can I have VSCode running scripts in its own internal terminal?
Thank you in advance!